# If two functions are close apart can I prove the difference of their empirical loss is also small?

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normed-spaces, neural-networks

> I am trying to understand the  proof of Theorem 3 in the paper ["A Universal Law of Robustness via isoperimetry"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12806.pdf) by Bubeck and Sellke.

---

Basically there exist atleast one $w_{L,e}$ in $\mathcal{W}_{L,e}$ for which there is another $w_{L}$ in $\mathcal{W}_{L}$  $\frac{\epsilon}{6j}$ apart.

And this this makes clear,
$$||f_{w_{L,\epsilon}} - f_{w_{L}} ||_{\infty} = J *  \epsilon/ 6J = \epsilon/6  \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot (a) $$

using this assumption $1$

$$\boxed{
\left\|f_{\boldsymbol{w}_{1}}-f_{\boldsymbol{w}_{2}}\right\|_{\infty} \leq J\left\|\boldsymbol{w}_{1}-\boldsymbol{w}_{2}\right\|}
$$

This equation (a) denotes that those two functions are close apart.

How can I prove empirical loss of $f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}$ and $f_{w_{L}}$ are also close? Here the label is $y$

---

My thoughts:-
Let,

$p_{1}$ = $(y_{i} - f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i}))$ and $p_{2}$ = $(y_{i} - f_{w_{L}}(x_{i}))$

Has to proof:-  $p_{2}^2$ < $p_{1}^2$ + (some constant)

then I  can conclude from here that $EL(f_{w_{L}}) \leq EL(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}})$ + (some constant)

If this holds I   can  say that $EL(f_{w_{L}})$  being small implies $EL(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}})$ can't be too big

But How can I proof

$$\boxed{p_{2}^2 \leq p_{1}^2 + C }$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To Prove:- $$\boxed{p_{2}^2 \leq p_{1}^2 + C }$$

Given :- $$p_{1} = (y_{i} - f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i}))$$ and $$p_{2} = (y_{i} - f_{w_{L}}(x_{i}))$$

---

$$p_{2}^2 - p_{1}^2 = (f_{w_{L}}(x_{i})^2 - f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i})^2) + 2 y_{i} (f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i}) - f_{w_{L}}(x_{i})) \leq$$ $$[(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i}) + f_{w_{L}}(x_{i}))] [|f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i}) - f_{w_{L}}(x_{i})|] + 2 y_{i} \frac{\epsilon}{6} \leq$$

$$[(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}(x_{i}) + f_{w_{L}}(x_{i}))][\frac{\epsilon}{6}] + 2 y_{i} \frac{\epsilon}{6} \leq Constant $$

Hence Proved.